# PMD: How to ignore short variable names in lambda expressions only

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lambda, pmd

I'm looking for a solution that allows me to check short variable names with PMD, while excluding lambdas from this rule.

Mainly, the reason for this is that IntelliJ auto-names common lamba variables with single characters, esp. `java.lang.String`s that are always abbreviated like

```
aListFullOfStrings.forEach(s -> s.replaceAll(" ", ""));
```

I prefer that abbreviation but I don't want to add suppressions to all my lambdas. I couldn't find any way to adjust my PMD rules in order to solve this gracefully.

Suggestions are much appreciated - I'm not that experienced with all their configurations.

Comment: This is a very interesting use case! I'm taking this to https://github.com/pmd/pmd/issues/720 so it can be taken into future PMD releases.

Comment: @Johnco thank you, that will make things even easier. I'll keep an eye on that ticket : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage the `xpath` based suppression capabilities of PMD.

On your ruleset XML, simply configure the property for this particular rule as so:

```
<rule ref="rulesets/java/naming.xml/ShortMethodName">
  <properties>
    <property name="violationSuppressXPath" value=".[ancestor::LambdaExpression]"/>
  </properties>
</rule>
```

Non the less, as a PMD maintainer, I believe this is a legitimate case for altering the rule on PMD itself, so I've added github.com/pmd/pmd/issues/720 to track this.

Comment: this worked perfectly for my setup with maven-pmd-plugin

Answer (score 1):

By default PMD will flag variables with names of less than 3 characters, although it already exempts some legitimate cases such as for-loop variables. You need to tweak PMD so that it also exempts variables within lambda expressions.

That's done by amending one of PMD's many ruleset files named **naming.xml** which resides within the jar file **{pmd installation dir}\lib\pmd-java-5.8.1.jar** (if you are using the latest release of PMD). One approach is as follows:

- Extract the contents of the jar file **pmd-java-5.8.1.jar** to some temporary folder.
- Edit the extracted file **naming.xml** and locate the text **rule name="ShortVariable"** then insert the text **[not(ancestor::LambdaExpression)]** as shown in bold below.

> [not(ancestor::ForInit)]
>   **[not(ancestor::LambdaExpression)]**
>   [not(../../VariableDeclarator and ../../../LocalVariableDeclaration
>   and ../../../../ForStatement)]
>   [not((ancestor::FormalParameter) and (ancestor::TryStatement))]

- Optionally, you can also make further tweaks to the ruleset files.
- Recreate the jar file using the modified **naming.xml**. This command does that:

  **jar cf pmd-java-5.8.1.jar net rulesets META-INF**

I don't know what flavor and version of the PMD plugin you have, but they should all be using **pmd-java-5.8.1.jar** or some earlier version of it. I just did a simple proof-of-concept using PMD itself rather than a plugin, and verified it from the command line for a class with this method:

```
void test() {
    Consumer<String> consumer = (String s) -> System.out.println(s);
    consumer.accept("Hello world!!!");
}
```

Version 5.8.1 of PMD reported the violation shown below for the lambda variable in that code:

[image: violation for short variable]

However, after modifying **naming.xml** as described above that violation was gone.

Comment: Thanks for this great in-detail answer. I tried it and it worked perfectly - additionally I learned something about how PMD is structured inside. The only reason I accepted the other answer is that the external configuration was a better solution for my use case. Nonetheless, it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Newer PMD version uses ShortVariable rule in naming ruleset now. I used this in my ruleset.xml to make the error go away for just lambdas. It still catches short non-lambda variables.

```
<rule ref="rulesets/java/naming.xml/ShortVariable">
    <properties>
        <property
                name="violationSuppressXPath" value=".[ancestor::LambdaExpression]"/>
    </properties>
</rule>
```